# Using jQuery AJAX to redirect user on button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery AJAX function. I want to redirect my user to a webpage when he clicks a button. Please do not tell me to target the button to the webpage as I have to do some working in the php file... My current code is :-

TEST.html file :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("test2.php");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<button>Get External Content</button>
<div id="div1"></div>

</html>
```

Now my test2.php file is the following :-

```
<?php header("Location:http://google.com"); ?>
```

I am a beginner in AJAX jQuery. So, please do not downvote my post although it may sound silly. My code, for obvious reasons is not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant redirect with an AJAX call. You can either create a simple link or link to a PHP page which then redirects the user on. Using AJAX will only let you manipulate this page you are on.

Of course, you can always redirect with simple Javascript as well.

```
window.location = '/my_url.php';
```

**EDIT**: In response to your comment question, what I would do is use the .get() function with the data parameter, check what has been returned from the PHP page if server side validation is required and then if I am happy with the result, redirect.

If no server side validation is needed, there is no need for AJAX.

Comment: Thanks...I got it...first carry on the php work and then redirect using JS

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: AJAX is requesting and reading the .php file. When AJAX sees the `header("Location: ...")` line, it **redirects the AJAX request**. Put simply, AJAX can't be used for redirects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the complete callback to redirect the user after the AJAX query has completed like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("test2.php", 
      complete: function(){
        window.location = 'http://new_url';
      }
    );
  });
});
```

That being said if you just want to redirect a user on a button click there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").load("test2.php");
```

appends the contents which are 
returned from `test2.php` , it will not redirect. The `test2.php` should return a link and populate the div with the link. Then write a callback on ajax success which will 
redirect using `window.location = target` , the target being the link which was dynamically loaded in the `div1`